# Polymer-redux : How to store data in redux using polymer?

Tags: redux, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have created polymer app with redux. redux working fine, it stored data. but when I reload page it flush the data. how can I store data for next page? I want to store data in redux like local storage. Can anyone help me?

**Thanks in advance.**

here my redux code

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer-redux/polymer-redux.html">
<script src="../../node_modules/redux/dist/redux.min.js"></script>

<script>
    const initialState = {
        user: {"username":"admin", "password":123},
        isLoggedIn: false,
        friends : ["Mahadev"]
    };

    const reducer = (state, action) => {
        if(!state) return initialState;
        switch(action.type){
            case "UPDATE_LOGGEDIN":
                state.isLoggedIn = action.isLogin;
                return Object.assign({}, state, {isLoggedIn:state.isLoggedIn});
            case "ADD_FRIEND":
                let friends = state.friends.slice(0);
                friends.push(action.friend);
                return Object.assign({}, state, {friends:friends});
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }

    const store = Redux.createStore(reducer, initialState);
    const ReduxMixin = PolymerRedux(store);
</script>
```

Polymer Login page script

```
<script>
    class LoginPage extends ReduxMixin(Polymer.Element){
        static get is(){ return "login-page"; }

        static get properties(){
            return {
                user: {
                    type: Array,
                    statePath: "user"
                }
            };
        }

        static get actions(){
            return {
                loggenIn : function(isLogin){
                    return {
                        type: "UPDATE_LOGGEDIN",
                        isLogin: isLogin
                    };
                }
            };
        }

        _doLogin(){
            let username = this.$.username;
            let userpass = this.$.userpass;
            if(username.value && userpass.value) {
                if ((username.value == this.user.username) && (userpass.value == this.user.password)) {
                    this.dispatch("loggenIn", true);
                    window.history.pushState({}, null, '/home-page');
                    window.location.reload(true);
                } else {
                    alert("Invalid username or password !");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    window.customElements.define(LoginPage.is, LoginPage);
</script>
```

Comment: You can't reload. Once you reload, your store is gone. Nothing is Redux shares *between* apps. Look at Polycasts #61 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PahsgJn0sgU) and #62 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2FxAT1u8pU&t=1s), where Rob Dodson showed using Redux with Polymer 1.0. I updated the code for Polymer 2.0 at https://github.com/johnthad/polycast61 and https://github.com/johnthad/polycast62.

Comment: I sow that videos. But we can store that in local. I sow that type of application.